# $1_{R}$ in Subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A subring of $R$ is defined to be a subgroup of $(R,+,0_{R})$ that is closed under multiplication. I can't prove that $1_{R}$ is in a subring using this definition. Is it possible for $1_{R}$ to be not in a subring? According to some textbooks, $1_{R}$ is included in the definition of a ring. But since a subring is also a ring, does this contradict with the definition of a ring?

Comment: What, exactly, is your definition of "ring" and "subring"?

Comment: Yeah I mean it's confusing.   Rings without unity are sometimes called Rngs.  I've heard ideals described as a certain kind of subring.   But obviously Rng is meant,  because if it contains unity it's the whole ring.   I guess it depends on the author.  I would think that a subring is a subset that is a ring.  So if you require unity,  ok.

Comment: @morrowmh According to my professor, ring $R$ is an abelian group $(R, +, 0_{R})$ with the operation $\cdot$ that satisfies: 1) $\cdot$ is associative and distributes over $+$. 2) $\exists 1_{R}\in R$ such that $1_{R}u=u=u1_{R}, \forall u\in R$. The definition of subring is just the first sentence of my post.

Comment: As you’ve defined “subring”, the set $\{0\}$ is a subring. So clearly your definition does not entail that $1$ is in the subring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the definition of *ring* includes a multiplicative identity $1$, then it is standard that the definition of *subring* also requires containing the same multiplicative identity element $1$. This is a definition, not a theorem (it doesn't follow from the other parts of the definition), but it's in line with the standard convention that homomorphisms of algebraic structures preserve all the specified structure, which in this case includes the multiplicative identity.

(This rules out, for example, $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ being a subring of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ as unital rings: even though it has a multiplicative identity $(1, 0)$, it's not equal to $(1, 1)$, the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.)